# Error: Missing Dependency: python >= 2.6 is needed by package ambari-server-1.7.0-169.noarch

Tags: linux, unix, centos, bigdata, hortonworks-data-platform

While installing ambari server, getting following error and after installing python 2.6 and forming softlink yum stops working.

Please find the error:--

> yum install -y ambari-server
>
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
>
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  * base: centos.aol.com  *
>   epel: ftp.wallawalla.edu  * extras: ftp.usf.edu  * updates:
>   ftp.ussg.iu.edu Setting up Install Process Resolving Dependencies
>
> --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package ambari-server.noarch 0:1.7.0-169 set to be updated
>   --> Processing Dependency: postgresql-server >= 8.1 for package: ambari-server
>   --> Processing Dependency: python >= 2.6 for package: ambari-server
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package ambari-server.noarch 0:1.7.0-169 set to be updated
>   --> Processing Dependency: python >= 2.6 for package: ambari-server
>   ---> Package postgresql-server.x86_64 0:8.1.23-10.el5_10 set to be updated
>   --> Processing Dependency: postgresql = 8.1.23-10.el5_10 for package: postgresql-server
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package ambari-server.noarch 0:1.7.0-169 set to be updated
>   --> Processing Dependency: python >= 2.6 for package: ambari-server
>   ---> Package postgresql.x86_64 0:8.1.23-10.el5_10 set to be updated
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution ambari-server-1.7.0-169.noarch from
>
> Updates-ambari-1.7.0 has depsolving problems   --> Missing Dependency:
>   python >= 2.6 is needed by package ambari-server-1.7.0-169.noarch
>   (Updates-ambari-1.7.0) Error: Missing Dependency: python >= 2.6 is
>   needed by package ambari-server-1.7.0-169.noarch
>
> (Updates-ambari-1.7.0)  You could try using --skip-broken to work
>   around the problem  You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
>                           package-cleanup --dupes
>                           rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 5 comes with Python 2.4. Either rebuild the packages you are trying to install or use a repo for that version of CentOS.